# Maven release plugin. branch release fails (+ missing first letter of branch name)

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea, mercurial, maven-release-plugin

**Added**

If my branch is **default**, `maven:prepare` completed successfully.

**/Added**

I have maven project in Idea. Using mercurial.
I have created branch "**MAVEN_RELEASE**" to try to release it with maven-release-plugin. And got the following error. Please follow the **hg push** line. Is cause of the problem is **AVEN_RELEASE** (no first letter)?

```
[INFO] [INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] [INFO] Total time: 02:16 min
[INFO] [INFO] Finished at: 2016-05-12T17:53:53+06:00
[INFO] [INFO] Final Memory: 63M/216M
[INFO] [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Checking in modified POMs...
[INFO] EXECUTING: cmd.exe /X /C "hg branch"
[INFO] EXECUTING: cmd.exe /X /C "hg outgoing"
[WARNING] A different branch than AVEN_RELEASE was found in outgoing changes, branch name was MAVEN_RELEASE. Only local branch named AVEN_RELEASE will be pushed.
[INFO] EXECUTING: cmd.exe /X /C "hg commit --message "[maven-release-plugin] prepare release sea-bni-1.0.5" C:\EA\IdeaProjects\sea-eclipse\pom.xml C:\EA\IdeaProjects\sea-eclipse\jnlp-apps\pom.xml C:\EA\IdeaProjects\sea-eclipse\jnlp-apps\arm-data-entry\pom.xml C:\EA\IdeaProjects\sea-eclipse\jnlp-apps\sea-print\pom.xml C:\EA\IdeaProjects\sea-eclipse\sea-web\pom.xml C:\EA\IdeaProjects\sea-eclipse\the-ear\pom.xml"
[INFO] EXECUTING: cmd.exe /X /C "hg push -rAVEN_RELEASE http://oksapp.bingo.ru/hg/sea-eclipse"
[ERROR] 
EXECUTION FAILED
  Execution of cmd : push failed with exit code: 255.
  Working directory was: 
    C:\EA\IdeaProjects\sea-eclipse
  Your Hg installation seems to be valid and complete.
    Hg version: 3.5.2 (OK)
```

Second question, please:
2) Should I do deploy action before doing maven release prepeare, perform?

Answer (score 0):

Should be resolved in maven-scm-plugin version 1.9.5, but I have no luck using it... https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SCM-682